# ListView didn't showing data in Fragment at Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, arrays, android-listfragment, navigation-drawer

i had problem that my string-array not showing in listview at ListFragment, i didn't get any error, just the data of string-array not display. i create a navigation drawer that show data form another fragment

here my ListFragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FragmentFood extends ListFragment  {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food,container,false);
    String[] food = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.food_array);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,food);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

String nama;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
Fragment fragment = null ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    nama = intent.getStringExtra("Nama");

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView tvNama = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    tvNama.setText(nama);


    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragment = new  FragmentFood();
        callFragment(fragment);
    }

    /*FragmentFood fragmentFood = (FragmentFood) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentfood");

    if (fragmentFood == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.frame_content,null,"fragmentfood");
        transaction.commit();
    }*/


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    ListFragment listFragment=null;
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_food) {
        listFragment = new FragmentFood();
        callFragment(listFragment);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_dessert) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_drink) {
        /*fragment = new FragmentDrink();
        callFragment(fragment);*/
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_chartpayment) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_status) {

    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void callFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

fragment_food.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp">

<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

i dont have any idea to show data in ListFragment at NavigationDrawer

Comment: Please show us setListAdapter?

Comment: Try to user ArrayAdapter<String> instead of ArrayAdapter.....and if you have costum adapter than show code of that class.

Comment: theres no more code. just MainActivity.java(contain navdrawer and frame_layout), FragmentFood.java, and fragment_food.xml.